# Raspberry pi Qt plotting with high CPU usage

Tags: c++, qt, plot, raspberry-pi, cross-compiling

I use Qt creator cross-compile on Raspberry pi B+ to develope an App that plot data from file. The program work fine on my laptop but the plot use hi processing on pi B+. when I run the program on my laptop it work with less than 1% of CPU and on pi with 1-2% CPU, when I start the plotting on my Laptop it take about 13% CPU but on pi it take about 95-99% cpu!!!. Plotting on my laptop rich more than 60 frame per second but on pi just 14-16 frame per second and when I overclocked the pi I got about 35 frame per second. my laptop run Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome shell and the CPU is intel centrino core 2 Dou 2 GHz with 4 GB RAM and NVIDIA. This is the source code of my Qt App

```
    #include "mainwindow.h"
    #include "ui_mainwindow.h"


    ///*********** STARTING THE CLASS **************************///
    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
        QMainWindow(parent),
        ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        MainWindow::plotting();
    //********************* Read File **************************//
        QFile inputFile("ECG_Data.txt");
        if (inputFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
        {
           QTextStream in(&inputFile);
           int i=0;
           while (!in.atEnd())
           {
              QString line = in.readLine();
              fileData[i]=line.toDouble();
              i++;
           }
           inputFile.close();
        }

    }


    ///**************** START BUTTON *************************///
    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
    {
        stop= true;
    }
    ///***************** STOP BUTTON **************************///
    void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
    {
        stop = false;

    }

    ///**************** PLOTTING *******************************///
    void MainWindow::plotting()
    {
    //***** set plot parameters *******************************//
        ui->customPlot->addGraph();
        ui->customPlot->graph(0)->setPen(QPen(Qt::yellow)); //set plot line color
        ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTickLabelType(QCPAxis::ltDateTime);
        ui->customPlot->xAxis->setDateTimeFormat("hh:mm:ss");
        ui->customPlot->xAxis->setAutoTickStep(false);
        ui->customPlot->xAxis->setTickStep(2);
        ui->customPlot->axisRect()->setupFullAxesBox();

    //***** set plot background color ****************************//
        QLinearGradient plotGradient;
        plotGradient.setStart(0, 0); //set start point
        plotGradient.setFinalStop(0, 350); //set final point
        plotGradient.setColorAt(1, QColor(100, 100, 100)); // set background color
        ui->customPlot->setBackground(plotGradient);

    //***** creat connection for plot Axes *************************//
        // make left and bottom axes transfer their ranges to right and top axes:
        connect(ui->customPlot->xAxis, SIGNAL(rangeChanged(QCPRange)), ui->customPlot->xAxis2, SLOT(setRange(QCPRange)));
        connect(ui->customPlot->yAxis, SIGNAL(rangeChanged(QCPRange)), ui->customPlot->yAxis2, SLOT(setRange(QCPRange)));


    //***** creat connection for plot founction *********************//
        // setup a timer that repeatedly calls MainWindow::realtimeDataSlot();
        connect(&dataTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(readResponse()));
        dataTimer.start(10); // Interval 0 means to refresh as fast as possible

    }

///**************** REAL TIME PLOTTING SLOT *********************///
    void MainWindow::readResponse()

    { if(j==500){j=0;}

        double value0 = fileData[j];
        if (stop)
        {j++;
    //***** calculate two new data points: **************************//
        double key = QDateTime::currentDateTime().toMSecsSinceEpoch()/1000.0; //first data point of plot from time
        static double lastPointKey = 0;
        if (key-lastPointKey > 0.01) // at most add point every 10 ms
        { //emit plottingData(rx);
        //  double value0 = rxplot; // convert string data of serial port to Double to be the second data point of plot

    //***** add data to lines: *****************************//
          ui->customPlot->graph(0)->addData(key, value0);
          // remove data of lines that's outside visible range:
          ui->customPlot->graph(0)->removeDataBefore(key-2);
          ui->customPlot->graph(0)->rescaleValueAxis();
          lastPointKey = key;
        }
//make key axis range scroll with the data (at a constant range size of 8):
        ui->customPlot->xAxis->setRange(key+0.25, 2, Qt::AlignRight);
        ui->customPlot->replot();

//***** calculate frames per second: *********************************//
        static double lastFpsKey;
        static int frameCount;
        ++frameCount;
         if (key-lastFpsKey > 2) // average fps over 2 seconds
         { ui->statusBar->showMessage(QString("%1 FPS, Total Data points: %2").arg(frameCount/(key-lastFpsKey), 0, 'f', 0).arg(ui->customPlot->graph(0)->data()->count()), 0 );
          lastFpsKey = key;
          frameCount = 0;
         }
         }

    }

    ///****************** DESTRUCTOR ****************************///
    MainWindow::~MainWindow()
    {
        delete ui;

    }
```

The App work with full screen on pi "this is the second problem" and don't receive touch event from the touchscreen. I use Qt 5.4 and on pi the operating system is Raspbian Wheezy. I fllowed this instractions to configure the cross-compile on pi [here.](http://exploreembedded.tumblr.com/post/115333857238/guide-to-cross-compile-qt-54-for-the-raspberry-pi)

[This is the photo of App window on pi screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh58q.jpg)

please help me :(

Comment: The CPU of the Pi is very, very, very slow. No surprises here. There isn't much you can do, aside from porting your drawing to GL.

Comment: @ddriver or use more efficient cpu rendering. There's a bunch of techniques for CPU drawing that don't require to redraw the whole graph each frame. Or you know, not waste time on things like anti-aliasing the lines.

Comment: ddriver & PeterT , thank you for fast replay. I did increase the GPU memory but no thing happened. What you suggest to improve the rendering? Are you advice me to buy pi2

Comment: @QudorEng i suggest you to try to new QtCharts library. Also i want to mention that current qcustomplot is not so powerfull and optimized.

Comment: @tty6 Do you think the QtChart need less processing than qcustumplot?

Comment: @QudorEng i'm sure that QtCharts has OpenGL support. All my tries to make qcustomplot to run graph rendering with OpenGL failed.

Comment: @tty6 Are the QtCharts support the real-time plotting? because I want to plot the real-time signal that received from the serial port